# Printing A MongoDB Date From PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, date

How in `PHP` do I get the regular timestamp format out of a `MongoDB` date?

Assume I have:

```
$my_date;
print_r($my_date);
```

The `print_r` output is:

```
MongoDate Object ( [sec] => 1346300336 [usec] => 593000 )
```

But doing:

```
echo $my_date;
```

Outputs:

```
0.59300000 1346300336
```

Even tried:

```
echo (string)$my_date
```

Same thing.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`$my_date->sec` is the unix timestamp, use `date()` function to show it in required format.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $my_date->sec);
```

Comment: Not sure who's decision at 10Gen that was, but it is confusing. Shouldn't have to call the `sec` property. Ohh well.

Comment: that person actually has a handle here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4243/kristina

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick update, to say that MongoDate has a toDateTime method since the version 1.6 of the pecl extension.
You can now do

```
$mongoDate->toDateTime()->format(...)
```

Answer (score 2):

you are missing the microsecond.

To show (mongo -> php)

```
$fecha = date(preg_replace('`(?<!\\\\)u`', $my_date->usec, 'Y-M-d H:i:s.u'), $my_date->sec);
//MongoDate ISODate("2013-05-28T15:27:24.735Z")
//Php Date 2013-May-28 10:27:24.735000
```

To send to mongo (php -> mongo)

```
$fecha_mongo = new MongoDate(strtotime($fecha));
//Fail function, the short way but, 70000 isn't equal to 700000.
//$fecha_mongo->usec = (int)$fecha_micro->format("u");
preg_match("/\.(.*)/", $fecha, $uSec);
$fecha_mongo->usec = (int)(count($uSec)==2?$uSec[1]:0);

//Php Date 2013-May-28 10:27:24.735000
//MongoDate ISODate("2013-05-28T15:27:24.735Z")
```

Good day!

Mario T.

Answer (score 1):

Use [MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-bson-utcdatetime.php) [MongoDate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php) is deprecated

```
$mongoDate = new \MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime(strtotime('2020-10-01 18:30:00'));
```

Answer (score 0):

First, create date from  millisecond using given function:

```
public function showdatefn($mili)
{   
    $seconds = (string)$mili / 1000;
    return date("d-m-Y", $seconds); 
}   
$date =$this->showdatefn(<put mongo date here>);
```

This will give you correct date.