# Get timestamp from mongodb database saved with ISODate

Tags: php, mysql, mongodb

I used

```
$collection = $db->mpres_seq ;
$document = array(
    "id" => new MongoInt64(1),
    "last_executed" => new MongoDate(strtotime("2012-04-01 04:00:00")),
    "last_message" => ""
);
```

$collection->insert($document);
 this code to insert timestamp data. and now i want to get it back.I want the same type(and format) of `Unix_Timestamp(last_executed)` in mysql. How can i do that?

```
> db.mpres_seq.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("528a3a2af7bde99408000080"),
    "id" : NumberLong(1),
    "last_executed" : ISODate("2012-04-01T02:00:00Z"),
    "last_message" : ""
```

}

This is a sample result.

Comment: You need to get the sec property of returned date.

See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190136/printing-a-mongodb-date-from-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to use [mongodate](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodate.php).

> For showing a human readable MongoDate, you can use something like
>   this:

```
<?php 
date('Y-M-d h:i:s', $yourDate->sec);
```