# How to select MongoDate in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to select MongoDate? I have code like this:

```
<?php
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('jam');

$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
$today = new MongoDate($ts);

$query = $db->test;
$query->insert(array("today"=>$today));
?>
```

That's code for inserting MongoDate but I can't catch in format ('Y-m-d'). Here's my selecting code:

```
<?php
$conn = new Mongo();
$db = $conn->selectDB('jam');

$dt = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$ts = $dt->getTimestamp();
$today = new MongoDate($ts);

$query = $db->tes;
$cursor = $query->find();
foreach($cursor as $id=>$b){
        echo "<h2><a href='formlist2.php?id=".$id."'>".$b['today']."</h2>";
        }
?>
```

But the results are:

```
0.00000000 1484352000
0.00000000 1484352000
0.00000000 1484352000
```

Comment: What do you mean "can't catch in format"? Is it inserting correctly? Are you having trouble reading it?

Comment: Yeah, I've trouble to reading from my database. I know how to inserting data to database but I don't know how to reading from database. :(

Comment: Have you tried anything? Do you want the whole document, several documents, just the date from the document?

Comment: look at the top, I've changed my post. What do you think about it ?

Comment: Much better (+1) but remove the image and put the program output in your question as text please. Use code or quote formatting. Text should never be supplied as images, since it is not compatible with clipboards, search engines and screen readers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing A MongoDB Date From PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190136/printing-a-mongodb-date-from-php)

Comment: Already changed. Look at the top again.

Comment: Great. See the duplicate question I found!

Comment: Omg sir, thank you so much. I've solved the problem.